# redis-server connection issue after restoring of 5gb dump file

Tags: redis

I am using redis server of version 6.0.6 in ubuntu server. We have 3 node cluster, one master and two slaves. Its working fine. I have stopped all redis-servers and restored 5gb dump file. the moment I restored onwards the redis cluster is not connecting from redis desktop manager and from application as well. I am not getting any error logs also, from client its showing error

```
 cannot load databases:
```

but in logs its not showing any errors.

Comment: I have tried with windows single node version 3.2 with restored dump file of 5gb, Its working fine